# Backbone.js with Google Maps API Events?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

So I am using google maps api and the library provides me with this event:

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

This works if I just put it in my JS file, but how does that translate in a View with Backbone.js? How I implement this with the framework? I tried with .on in the initialize function, but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google map api events aren't DOM events, so you don't wire them up the same way in your view. I just put my google addListener calls inside the initialize function of whatever view is relevant and call any additional methods from inside the callback function you provide to the addListener call (just be sure to save a reference to this first so you can properly call any other view methods in there.)

example:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {

        var self = this;

        // assuming that map variable is defined here, otherwise pass in a reference to it through view options
        map = new google.maps.Map(blah blah blah);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            self.handleZoomChanged();
        });
    },

    handleZoomChanged: function () {
        // do whatever here
    }
};
```